# Powershell PowerBIActivityEvent Date Invalid

Tags: powershell, powerbi

#LoginToPowerBI
Login-PowerBI

#OutPutFile
$OutPutFilePath = "c:\temp\PowerBIAuditLog.txt"

$day= get-date  "2023-02-27"

Write-Output $day

$s = 1

$periodStart=$day.AddDays(-$s)
$base=$periodStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Write-Output $base

$GetActivity = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ($base+'T00:00:00.000') -EndDateTime ($base+'T23:59:59.999') -ActivityType 'ViewReport' -ResultType JsonString | ConvertFrom-Json

write-host $GetActivity

I get below error

Get-PowerBIActivityEvent : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
At line:20 char:16

- ... tActivity = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ($base+'T00:00:00 ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...BIActivityEvent:GetPowerB
    IActivityEvent) [Get-PowerBIActivityEvent], HttpOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest',M
    icrosoft.PowerBI.Commands.Admin.GetPowerBIActivityEvent

#LoginToPowerBI
Login-PowerBI

#OutPutFile
$OutPutFilePath = "c:\temp\PowerBIAuditLog.txt"

$day= get-date  "2023-02-27"

Write-Output $day

$s = 1

$periodStart=$day.AddDays(-$s)
$base=$periodStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Write-Output $base

$GetActivity = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ($base+'T00:00:00.000') -EndDateTime ($base+'T23:59:59.999') -ActivityType 'ViewReport' -ResultType JsonString | ConvertFrom-Json

write-host $GetActivity

I get below error , If I just have Get-date it works but setting a specific date wont work ?

Get-PowerBIActivityEvent : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
At line:20 char:16

- ... tActivity = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ($base+'T00:00:00 ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...BIActivityEvent:GetPowerB
    IActivityEvent) [Get-PowerBIActivityEvent], HttpOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest',M
    icrosoft.PowerBI.Commands.Admin.GetPowerBIActivityEvent

Comment: VERBOSE: Request Uri: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='2023-02-26T00:00:00.000'&endDateTime='2023-02-26T23:59:59.999'&$filter=Activity eq 'ViewReport'
VERBOSE: Status Code: BadRequest (400)

Comment: Is this limition for Power BI to reflect activty for the last 30 days ???

Answer (score 0):

The activity data in Power BI's activity log is kept for 30 days only. You can't query it for dates older than that.

See [Track user activities in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing#choosing-a-log-source).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Guess need to save the activity load incrementally.